# creating a read only user in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle database and a user that has all privileges to access that database. Now I want to create a new read only user who can only get the DDL of that database and can only read the data. What are the least privileges or roles that are needed to be granted to the new user? I don't want to perform any kind of alter, update or delete on that database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle if you wish to create a user who has only the select privilege you do as shown below:

```
[oracle@testsrv]$ sqlplus / as sysdba


SQL> create user juser_read_only identified by test;
SQL> grant create session to user_read_only;
SQL> grant select any table to user_read_only;

Once you have granted these privileges you can connect as the new user.

SQL> conn user_ready_only/test
SQL> select * from scott.emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300
        30
```

If you wish to grant select on dictionary views then:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
SQL> grant select any dictionary to user_read_only;
```

If you wish the read_only user could select ddl of any objects belongs to any schema then:

```
SQL> grant SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to user_read_only;
SQL> conn user_read_only

    SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','EMPLOYEES','HR') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','EMPLOYEES','HR')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "HR"."EMPLOYEES"
   (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
        "FIRST_NAME"
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant the `create session` privilege in order for the user to be able to connect. Then grant the `select` privilege on every table the user needs to access. To grant the user the privilege to read **all** tables in the entire database you can use the `select any table` privilege.

I think the `PUBLIC` role has the execute privilege for the DBMS_METADATA package so the user should be able to extract the DDL of the tables automatically.